# Manually insert values into content type table

Tags: drupal, contenttype

I want to insert a record with some additional data which are not in the node table. The record type is same as forums. I have created those fields using content types for forum. If am inserting values to node table using `node_save()` vid and nid are automatically inserted as default.

Comment: Why do you need to add "custom" nid ? This a an auto-increment column in the database, you really should drupal do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to insert your own values on fields that are auto-increment. node_save() should do the work for you.

Comment: yes i got.. Its working well... but we have to get values as follows   $edit->field_example[0]['value'] = '100'